# How to set record on another form using appropriate ID?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two separate forms (Form1 and Form2). They have already been opened. When I set ID on the second form and push the button, the second form should be closed and set the appropriate ID in the first form. How to do that?

Comment: What's "ID"? Post relevant forms code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy ID data to Form1, in the Sub for button click:

```
Forms("Form1).Form.ID = Me.ID
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

If you want to scroll to the record on Form1 with ID=Form2.ID, you can use something like this:

```
With Form_Form1.Form.Recordset.Clone
  .FindFirst "[ID] = " & Me.ID
  Form_Form1.Form.Bookmark = .Bookmark
End With
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

If you want to filter Form1 and show only one record with ID=Form2.ID, set Filter property on Form1

```
Form_Form1.Form.Filter="[ID]=" & Me.ID
Form_Form1.Form.FilterOn = True
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

If ID is text, add quotes

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't actually what I want. Can I use GoToRecord method in that case or something like this?